# Is immigration unmanned at Mayotte airport when arriving from Paris?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, france, passport-stamps, mayotte

A Peruvian guy is flying from Paris to Mayotte (a French overseas department) on a direct Air Austral flight. He is visa-exempt for mainland France, but **not** for Mayotte.

When I flew from Paris to Guadeloupe and Réunion (also French overseas departments) Guadeloupean and Réunionnais immigration was unstaffed on arrival, meaning those in need of an entry stamp had no way of getting it. When exiting, however, checks took place.

Does it work the same when flying into Mayotte from Paris? If so, how can an entry stamp be obtained? Is one even needed, or will the mainland French exit stamp suffice?

Comment: I have this all the time in small or private airports. The pilot *SHOULD* know what to do when he files his flight plan. There is a procedure.  The lads at http://aviation.stackexchange.com/ *might* be helpful or they might not.

Comment: What is the visa exemption based on? It’s not his Peruvian citizenship, because that only allows him to enter Guadeloupe, Martinique and French Guiana without visa, but neither Mayotte nor mainland France.

Comment: @chirlu Wrong, Peruvians don't need a visa for the Schengen Area

Comment: The foreign ministry believes otherwise: http://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/en/coming-to-france/getting-a-visa/article/foreign-nationals-holding-ordinary-passports-exempt-from-visa-requirements

Comment: @chirlu Outdated in that case. It's a pretty new exemption http://www.schengenvisainfo.com/21982-peruvians-have-traveled-to-schengen-countries-without-visas/ https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=PE&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=FR&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C http://www.lima.diplo.de/Vertretung/lima/de/11/Visa.html

Comment: I see there were changes in 2016. That page may be outdated (bad for an official page, of course).

Comment: @GayotFow - This is a better fit for Travel than Aviation. It's definitely [OT](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) at Aviation. The pilot's job is to get the plane to the destination. Not his problem if you can't get through customs. (Only becomes his problem if he's at the end of his hours and has to stay for a rest period.)

Comment: @FreeMan actually the pilot can be fined and detained, possibly prosecuted. It's called trafficking.  Try it sometime at a small field like YJT.  But if it's OT at Aviation, we'll take it, thanks

Comment: See also http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/manifest.html

Comment: @GayotFow - Yikes! Didn't realize that. But yeah, this would generally be OT at Aviation.

Comment: @Crazydre we can give you an answer that says the pilot (or designated crew) must file a flight plan and manifest, but I doubt an accurate answer for specifically Mayotte would be immediately forthcoming. I know them generally from experience at North American and European fields but would have to contact the Operations Desk at Mayotte, etc. At some level everything will dovetail in to the Advance Passenger Information regime.

Comment: @GayotFow Is there anything in the question indicating that it will be a private flight? There are direct, commercial flights from Paris to Mayotte and starting to discuss if the pilot or the crew knows what to do sounds a little odd. The airport's web page seem to indicate a completely normal immigration control for all flights: http://www.aeroport-mayotte.com/gp/Documents-Formalites/89

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo the rules are the same for private and commercial flights.  If a given airport has permanent  immigration control that's fine, but the question is about an unstaffed airport.  Most of those are smaller fields and those will cater to the lighter aircraft. I don't think my comment is odd at all and wonder where you are coming from. But on the advice of Jeff Atwood, comments are second class citizens in the first instance. If you are knowledgeable in the area, give an answer so I can learn. Thanks.

Comment: @FreeMan countries typically fine air carriers for transporting passengers without proper documents, so without needing to get into more serious crimes like trafficking it might also be the pilot's problem as a responsibility he has to his employer.

Comment: Indeed, looking at the [Arrêté du 4 février 2015 relatif aux documents et visas exigés pour l'entrée des étrangers sur le territoire de Mayotte](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000030235682&categorieLien=id), the Peruvian guy will likely have to ask for a visa first (except diplomatical and special passports). Upon arrival, his visa is to be stamped. The same legal text mentions that there are two permanent checkpoints: the Dzaoudzi-Pamandzi airport and Dzaoudzi port.

Comment: @Francis Yup, there is a control point, but when I flew from Paris-CDG to Guadeloupe and Réunion, the booths were unstaffed on arrival and everyone just walked past them. I wonder if it's the same in Mayotte when arriving from Paris-CDG

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got myself a prepaid SIM card to call the airport cheaply.

Apparently the abolished entry checks for pax arriving from France **don't** apply in Mayotte, so everyone's still checked.